# Difference between PHP and .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, http-headers

Is there a difference between php header redirect and .htaccess redirect by the SEO of the site?

Answer (score 4):

Probably not - depends how you're doing your redirection.

In PHP:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser, emits 302 */
```

If you want to emit a 301, use:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/", true, 301);
```

More in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

If you're doing this in your `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 302 /PATH_TO_REDIRECT http://www.example.com/
```

then that'll emit a 302 too.

Again, making it emit a 301 is straightforward:

```
Redirect 301 /PATH_TO_REDIRECT http://www.example.com/
```

In general, for SEO, just do what makes sense. If something's moved permanently use 301, if something's moved temporarily (e.g. during a temporary reshuffle) use 302 (take a look at the [response code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If the header is the same, I don't think it matters at all.